# jQuery UI's accordion not expanded

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a page where I use accordion widget. I need to be able to open a page and have an accordion expanded on a particular section. jQuery UI is providing an option for it: ***[active](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-active)***, which is what I use. however when I open a page the accordion is collapsed. What am I missing?

My code looks like this when I view page source:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    active: 3,
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I'll take a shot.

You have to wrap the code in a $(function() { }); block. Like this:

```
<script>
     $(function() {
          $("#accordion").accordion({
               header: "h3",
               active: 3,
               collapsible: true,
               autoHeight: true
          });
     });
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yes, it is there. I have quite a few other functions there, I just plucked this one because it controls the accordion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it'd be great if you could post a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)... or just the page itself on the web.

i would say do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(function() {
          $("#accordion").accordion({
               header: "h3",
               active: 3,
               collapsible: true,
               autoHeight: true
          });
     });
});
```

this makes your code run only when the document is fully loaded. Your problem might be that jQuery is trying to expand something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: $(function() {

  $("body").css({ background: "url(/i/bgr" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) + ".gif)" } );

  $("#accordion").accordion({

   header: "h3",

   collapsible: true,

   autoHeight: false,

   active: 3

  });
});